# Intel movidius stick setup ldconfig igfxcmrt64.so is not a symbolic link

Tags: computer-vision, intel, openvino

I exactly followed the steps [here at Intel.com](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/OpenVINO-Install-Linux#Movidius-steps).
When I do `sudo ldconfig` I get the following error message:

```
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /opt/intel/common/mdf/lib64/igfxcmrt64.so is not a symbolic link
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libmfx.so.1 is not a symbolic link
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libva.so.2 is not a symbolic link
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libigdgmm.so.1 is not a symbolic link
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libva-glx.so.2 is not a symbolic link
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libmfxhw64.so.1 is not a symbolic link 
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libva-x11.so.2 is not a symbolic link
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libva-drm.so.2 is not a symbolic link
```

I checked the `opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64` directory, and it is indeed almost empty.

I tried reinstalling OpenVino, I tried reinstalling the mediaSDK component. Nothing is working.

Comment: Can you please, if possible, specify which version of OpenVINO gave you that problem ? If you can't editing the question to mention it was with R4 would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to install the older R3 version of OpenVino instead of the newest R4 version that came out this week, and no longer had problems. Don't know if it might just be something else at play too...

Answer (score 3):

I think Intel developer made mistake in installation package with copying the referred files instead of symmlinks. the solution is simple as well: go to the folder, delete the repeated files, and rebuild the symmlinks.

Answer (score 2):

To extend on @SunXishan answer, here is a script that converts the copied files to symlinks. This is for R5.0.1

```
sudo rm /opt/intel/common/mdf/lib64/igfxcmrt64.so
sudo ln -s /opt/intel/common/mdf/lib64/libigfxcmrt64.so /opt/intel/common/mdf/lib64/igfxcmrt64.so

sudo rm /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libva-x11.so.2
sudo ln -s /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libva-x11.so /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libva-x11.so.2

sudo rm /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libva.so.2
sudo ln -s /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libva.so /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libva.so.2

sudo rm /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libva-glx.so.2
sudo ln -s /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libva-glx.so /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libva-glx.so.2

sudo rm /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libva-drm.so.2
sudo ln -s /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libva-drm.so /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libva-drm.so.2

sudo rm /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libigdgmm.so.1
sudo ln -s /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libigdgmm.so /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libigdgmm.so.1

sudo rm /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libmfx.so.1
sudo ln -s /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libmfx.so /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libmfx.so.1

sudo rm /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libmfxhw64.so.1
sudo ln -s /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libmfxhw64.so /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/libmfxhw64.so.1
```